# How to if on two conditions where one can be either of several values

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to check that:

1. if the state is true and the connection type is not 2 or 6 then do something.
2. if state is false and connection type is either 2 or 6 then do something else.

I have the following if statements but at points it is using the wrong code:

```js
async setWiFiConnection(state){
        try{
            var connType = await driver.getNetworkConnection();
            if(state == true && connType != 2 && connType != 6){
                await driver.toggleWiFi();
            }else if(state == false && connType == 2 || connType == 6){
                await driver.toggleWiFi();
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        } 
    }
```

I think the issue is if the connection type is 6 even if state is true then the else if code is being executed.

Comment: `else if (!state && (connType == 2 || connType == 6))`

Comment: All the checks that you have are not doing a type check, state can be `"false"` and still go into the true scenario. You need `!==` where you have `!=` and `===` where you have `==`, plus where the state is true the OR symbol is `||`, `&` it's AND not OR, plus you need `(connType == 2 || connType == 6)` con conditions to be wrapped around `()`.

Comment: @DaveNewton that done the trick thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave Newton's answer was what I was after. I needed to stick the connType checks in brackets see below:

```js
async setWiFiConnection(state){
        try{
            var connType = await driver.getNetworkConnection();
            if(state == true && connType != 2 && connType != 6){
                await driver.toggleWiFi();
            }else if(state == false && (connType == 2 || connType == 6)){
                await driver.toggleWiFi();
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        } 
    }
```

Thanks Dave

Comment:  Operator precedence matters! [For reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)